# Create object if not exists in Django ImportExportModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have these two models:

> Profile_model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False)
    ...
```

> Investment_model.py

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    invested = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

and I have this admin:

> Investment_admin.py

```
class InvestmentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    ...
    firstname = fields.Field(attribute='profile', 
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Profile, field='firstname'), 
        column_name='firstname')
    lastname = fields.Field(attribute='profile', 
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Profile, field='lastname'), 
        column_name='lastname')
    email = fields.Field(attribute='email', 
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Profile, field='email'), 
        column_name='email')
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = (
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'email',
            'invested',)
        
        export_order = fields


class InvestmentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
        ...
        resource_class = InvestmentResource
        ...
```

I am using `django`'s `ImportExportModelAdmin` for bulk imports and exports but when I try to import, I get this error:

[image]

I get that its producing this error because the profile hasn't been created yet. But what do I have to do to implement an `update_or_create` inside the `ImportExportModelAdmin`?

Comment: I've never used this before, but maybe you could try this. Create backup models and import the data you will import to these models, but in these models, when connecting the profile to the `Investment` model, give `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` and `null=True, blank=True` properties. Then you can fill in the profile field of the `Investment` model and transfer it to the main models via Shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 is to use `before_import()` to scan through the dataset and create Profiles in batch if they do not exist already.

Option 2 is to override methods and create the profiles just before the `Investment` row is imported.  This is only necessary for new `Investment` objects.  This assumes that 'email' will uniquely identify a `Profile`, you will need to adjust this if not.

Note that `firstname` and `lastname` can be set on the `Profile` object before it is created.

```py
class InvestmentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    firstname = fields.Field(attribute='profile__firstname', 
        widget=CharWidget(), column_name='firstname')

    lastname = fields.Field(attribute='profile__lastname', 
        widget=CharWidget(), column_name='lastname')

    email = fields.Field(attribute='email', 
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Profile, field='email'), 
        column_name='email')

    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        self.email = row["email"]

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Create any missing Profile entries prior to importing rows.
        """
        if (
            new
            and not Profile.objects.filter(
                name=self.email
            ).exists()
        ):
            obj, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(
                name=self.email
            )
            if created:
                logger.debug(f"no Profile in db with name='{self.email}' - created")
                instance.profile = obj
```

Obviously the Profile creation will be a side-effect of an import, so you may need to consider using transactions if you don't want Profiles created if the import fails.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be able to create the instance after viewing the [logs](https://im.ge/i/TvcnNf) with the [code](https://im.ge/i/TvcJd1) you specified above. But it's still showing the same error Profile matching query does not exist.

Comment: possibly it's getting called in the "preview" phase (i.e. if you are using the admin interface).  Best to set a debugger and step through so you can see what is going on.

Comment: Alright. I will, thanks!

Comment: hi, can you delete the comment with the link to the chat, please? I wasn't able to block all the fields in one image. Thanks!

Comment: ok this has been done