# Import multiple models with only one csv file django import export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using django import export package. I have two models called Vineyard and VineyardUser. I also have a csv file that contains all the data for both the Vineyard and VineyardUser models (separated by one blank column). Here is my model (which has been simplified):

```
class Vineyard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    text = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)

class VineyardUser(models.Model):
    vineyard = models.OneToOneField(Vineyard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I want to click import on the Vineyard model in admin, and then it also created the VineyardUser object. How can I do that? Now it only creates Vineyard objects even though there is a VineyardUser data in that csv file.

I think we can use before_save_instance or after_save_instance but I'm not sure how to do that. Also one thing to note is that they may also have two fields with the same name.

Any suggestion or solution to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

After searching for a while, I found that we can use `before_import(dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs)`, access the dataset, and create the object from that. But I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: You may want to include a link to the `django-import-export` package you're using. There are a few solutions out there.

Comment: Hi, I've searched for many solutions, but still can't find it. Can you help me?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434475/39296) shows how to do this