# django-import-export exclude cannot work with a `fields.Field(ForeignKeyWidget(...`

Tags: django, django-import-export

I want `name` field be a description in export file, don't import it if it exists.

But it always find instances with `name` and got a return more than 2 error.

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180, null=True, blank=True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=180, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
  

class EmployeeFootprint(models.Model):
    rcsp = models.CharField(max_length=180, null=True, blank=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


class EmployeeFootprintResource(resources.ModelResource):
    employee = fields.Field(column_name='id_number', attribute='employee', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(models.Employee, 'id_number'))
    name = fields.Field(column_name='name', attribute='employee', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(models.Employee, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = models.EmployeeFootprint
        exclude = ['id', 'name']
        import_id_fields = ['employee', 'rcsp']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKeyWidget` requires that it can uniquely identify an instance in the FK table using the field you supply.

In your case, there are 2 or more rows in the `Employee` with the same `name` value, hence the import fails with `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

> I want name field be a description in export file, don't import it if it exists.

This is not possible because your `EmployeeFootprintResource` declares `name` which has an FK relationship to `Employee`, so there needs to be a single instance of employee identifiable by `name` in order for the import to work.

If you want to create the `Employee` record if it does not exist, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434475/39296)