# Import into tables from Django import_export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am struggling to populate `models` in Django by using `ForeignKey`. Let's say we have as in **[import_export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)** documentation the following example:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Book name', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=True, null=True, )
    ...
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can I implement `import_export` module that can check if there is an existing author by name (not by id), that is not case sensitive, and **that can generate a new author if it does not exist**?

As an example, let's say the CSV file looks like:

```
name,author,...,price,categories
J.R.R. Tolkien,Lord of the Rings,...,40,["cat1","cat2"]
```

Also, if there is a `DateTime` field, how to generate that in `ForeignKey` table?

**NOTE:** I know about use of natural key:

```py
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget

class AuthorManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

class Author(models.Model):

    objects = AuthorManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,)

# Only the author field uses natural foreign keys.
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    author = Field(
        column_name = "author",
        attribute = "author",
        widget = ForeignKeyWidget(Author, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

But I am not sure how to check for `UPPER` or `lower` case in the CSV. And how to generate a new `Author` if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of creating an FK relation during import if it does not already exist.

#### Option 1 - override the `before_import_row()` method

```py
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    # note use of 'iexact' for case-insensitive lookup
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        author_name = row["author"]
        Author.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact=author_name, 
            defaults={"name": author_name})

    # other code omitted
```

#### Option 2 - subclass `ForeignKeyWidget`

Simply subclass `ForeignKeyWidget` and implement the check in `clean()`:

```py
class AuthorForeignKeyWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):

    def clean(self, value, row=None, **kwargs):
        author, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact=value,
            defaults={"name": value})
        return author


class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    author = fields.Field(
        column_name='author',
        attribute='author',
        widget=AuthorForeignKeyWidget(Author))

    # other code omitted
```

Either way will work fine.  I would personally use option 2.

> Also, if there is a DateTime field, how to generate that in ForeignKey table?

Since you are calling `Author.objects.get_or_create()` you can add a date if you wish, for example:

```py
author, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact=value, 
    defaults={"name": value, "created": timezone.now()})
```

If using natural keys you can adjust the code as desired.

[Related answer about creating in bulk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434475/39296)

Comment: This is great! Amazing! But what happens if I have two columns (`author_name` and `author_birthday`)? How do you populate both for the same model?

Comment: In both examples the row data is passed in, so you can read row values and pass to create()