# Django import-export - Import model with child from excel

Tags: django, import-from-excel, django-import-export

I have two models: `Project` and `Activity`. 
When registering a project, one or more associated activities can be added.

How can I import projects from xlsx, which include at least one activity?. I'm using the third party library `django-import-export`

I configure the project resource to export all the activities of each project in one cell separated by `/`, but I need the opposite, import all the activities of each project. I think that I must first save the `Project` for obtain the `id`, next extract the info from cell and finally save each activity associated, but I don't know how to do that.

My simplified models are:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    reg_date= models.DateField(
        default=date.today)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Activity(models.Model):
    schedule= models.ForeignKey(
        Project, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('schedule', 'date', 'description')
```

---

```
class ProjectResource(resources.ModelResource):
    activities = Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        import_id_fields = ['name']
        exclude = ('id',)
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        fields = ('reg_date',
            'name',
            'activities')
        
    def dehydrate_activities(self, obj):
        if obj.id:
            return "/".join([
                '({0} - {1})'.format(activity.date, activity.description) for activity in obj.projectactivity_set.all()
            ])

    def skip_row(self, instance, original, row, import_validation_errors=None):
        if original.name:
            return True
        return False
```

An example of exported file is:

| reg_date | name | activities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-10 | Project 1 | 2023-01-12-This is the first activity/2023-01-14-This is the second activity |
| 2023-01-10 | Project 2 | 2023-01-13-This is the first activity/2023-01-15-This is the second activity |

Comment: import-export has a few hooks to let you create data during import.  Refer to the docs, and [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74576058/39296) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `Activity` instances before you create the `Project` instances.

Then in your `Project` resource class you can define that a particular field is for foreign keys.

I've got an example;

```
from import_export import fields, resources, widgets

from apps.event.models import Occurrence

from ..models import Token


class TokenResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """ Integrate django-import-export with the Token model """
    occurrence = fields.Field(
        column_name='occurrence',
        attribute='occurrence',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Occurrence, 'id')
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'occurrence',
            'code',
        )
        model = Token
```

When using the `ForeignKeyWidget`, the first argument is the related model, then the second is a unique value that you can use to lookup the instance. It's that unique value that you then put in your import file to reference the related objects.

And my `Token` model has that relationship;

```
class Token(EnabledMixin, TimestampMixin, models.Model):
    """ Token for event entry. """

    class Meta:
        """ Meta class definition. """
        app_label = 'console'
        verbose_name = _("Token")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tokens")
        unique_together = ('code', 'occurrence')
        ordering = [
            'id',
        ]

    occurrence = models.ForeignKey(
        to='event.Occurrence',
        verbose_name=_("Event Occurrence"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='tokens',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```